# ANTLR4 Javascript get tree

Tags: javascript, parsing, tree, javascript-objects, antlr4

Currently I am busy with parsers and tried ANTLR. I understand the grammar so far and now I wanted to implement it in javascript.

Here is a small but important snippet of my code.

```js
if (selected == "Funktionen") {
      console.log("You selected functions")
      const chars = new antlr4.InputStream(data.stringToLex);
      const lexer = new FunktionLexer(chars);
      const tokens = new antlr4.CommonTokenStream(lexer);
      const parser = new FunktionParser(tokens);
      parser.buildParseTrees = true;
      const tree = parser.start();
      tree.accept(new Visitor());
}
```

My visitor looks like this

```js
class Visitor {
      visitChildren(ctx) {
        if (!ctx) {
          return;
        }
    
        if (ctx.children) {
          return ctx.children.map(child => {
            if (child.children && child.children.length != 0) {
              return child.accept(this);
            } else {
              return child.getText();
            }
          });
        }
      }
    }
```

I have oriented myself to this tutorial and everything works.
https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/javascript-target.md

http://lab.antlr.org/ Just hit on start and u will see what I mean.

The object of my tree I get back from my `start()` function with a right input looks like this:

[image]

The big problem is, I want to get the Tree and output it (at least in console log), like on the official ANTLR lab website.

Comment: There is no need to excuse yourself for being a starting/inexperienced developer (so I removed those remarks from your question since they're just noise). It is clear from your question you've tried quite a bit on your own: that is what counts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The big problem is, I want to get the Tree and output it

The object returned by `parser.start()` *is* the tree of your parsed input. You don't need a visitor for this.

What you mean by "and output it", I do not know. Just print it to your console? That can be done by doing:

```js
const tree = parser.start();

console.log(tree.toStringTree(parser));

// or if the line above doesn't work, try:
// console.log(tree.toStringTree());
```

Comment: That's right, but what I get back is an object without any structure even near to a tree. I'm looking for something like this: https://sebkraemer.github.io/posts/fints101-03-the-parse-tree/

Comment: Did a really good first step with the function toStringTree(), this already looks good, last step would be to put the string in a tree structure

Comment: @Ruffyg every parser rule returns an object that extends a `ParserRuleContext` (https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/runtime/JavaScript/src/antlr4/context/ParserRuleContext.js) which has a property `children`. These children are also `ParserRuleContext`s with (possibly) child nodes (the tree structure)

Comment: In your screenshot, the `children` property is visible.

Comment: And, did you understand what I mean? Do you see that the `children` property _is_ the tree structure?

Comment: Yes, I understood. My knowledge of the trees was the problem. :)